# Can you lay dominoes on a chessboard such that the chessboard cannot be cut without cutting one of the dominoes?

Tags: combinatorics

Pretty much what the title says. I was looking into the mutilated chessboard problem and I was thinking about this.

Basically, I noticed that no matter how you placed dominoes on a chessboard, they formed the same nice little rectangular sectors which meshed together to form the end chessboard. But is there a way to to place them differently? For example, placing a domino like so will make the chessboard unable to be cut in between the first and second row. Can we do this for all rows and columns? [diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HctWy.png)

I think it has something to do with odd/even number of tiles. Any thoughts? I'm almost certain it's not possible. Is there a way to rigorously prove the answer?

Comment: You might be interested in the mutilated chess board problem.

Answer (score 1):

Now, let me start this off by saying that I am by no means an artist. However, I think I found a solution to the proposed example problem:

[chessboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KI2Kw.png)

Note that this is just for a standard chessboard layout. So, it is possible, at least for this case.

Comment: Wow, I think you're right! I couldn't figure it out for the life of me.

Comment: Do you think it works for other sized chessboards? What about 6x6? (7x7 is out of the question since the dominoes wouldn't even fit)

Comment: Well, after working on the 6x6 case, it seems that there may very well be no solution here.

Comment: Yeah that seems to be it. But I'm not sure how to prove it.

Comment: My first observation is that any given pair of adjacent rows/columns needs to have an even # of dominoes across them.